# Using Windows Groups for Role Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

I am working with an asp.net application in .net 4.0. I have configured it to use windows integrated authentication.

What I want it to do is use the user groups on my pc/server as if they were roles. I can't find documentation or mention of it anywhere from my google results.

The reason this is required is because we have a COTS product which does this and we want to reuse the groups as roles.

Could I get an example or a pointer to some documentation so I can figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result here was that we communicated with our Sever Services team who were more than happy to help us use Active Directory to come up with a Corporate solution instead of using individual server user stores. This is a much better solution as the groups are reusable and integrate with other applications too.

The lesson here is that engagement with IT services with a business case is always worth the effort.